# Is Judicial activism legitimate?

Tags: law, judiciary

Is it preferable for a judiciary to interpret laws against the drafter's intent for reasons such as protecting minority rights or avoiding *arbitrary* use of the law? What are the effects of this?

Comment: Judicial activism usually means something more subtle than  "interpret laws against the intent of the drafter".

Comment: Voting to close - "judicial activism" is when the judiciary overreaches itself and encroaches on the domain of the legislature or executive. The powers of judicial review though are an essential feature of any independent judiciary as without it the courts cannot protect our rights.

Comment: In fact, at least in the US context, a crapton has been written even about how to define the term https://www.jstor.org/stable/3481421

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is "it depends."

- Some scholars believe that a law should always be interpreted according to the literal meaning of the words, whatever the drafters wanted to achieve. If they had wanted to say something else, they should have written it into the law. This raises the question if 'literal meaning' uses the present-day meaning of language or the historical meaning of language.
  This is seen as an important principle because it allows the reader of the law to understand it without looking up additional sources.
- Some scholars believe that when ambiguities in the law need to be resolved, statements of the drafters e.g. during the debate of the law should be used if they are available.
  This is seen as respecting the original decision of the legislators. If subsequent legislators want a different outcome, they are free to change the law.
- Some scholars believe that if there are several different interpretations of the law, and some are consistent with the constitution and others are not, then an interpretation consistent with the constitution should be chosen.
  This is seen as accepting the superiority of the constitution without having to go through centuries of legislation and e.g. replace "he" by "he or she" when the constitution clearly prescribes the legal equality of men and women.

The legal tradition of a country might lean towards one of the option, and there might even be laws and regulations directing the courts how to resolve any need for interpretation.

Comment: I'd add that as I understand, most legal cases don't go to court, or don't finish with a judgement from a judiciary ruling, unless the case itself is not something that'd be easy to adjudicate (i.e. Well understood, without facts both sides disputes, or is going badly for one side of a defendant, prosecutor, or complainant or plaintiff.) - there's usually a requirement *to* interpret the law around a given concept not defined well enough to not have confusion about how it should go down.

Comment: "raises the question if 'literal meaning' uses the present-day meaning of language or the historical meaning of language" also raises the question of determining the historical meaning.  For that matter, even the present-day meaning may be ambiguous, but the historical meaning is even more likely to be so.

Comment: @phoog, this is why there are judges and not just administrators.